# Access Denied in Asp .Net Core by Claims Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization

I have my login handler method. In that method I add claims from db to user.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(LoginModel.UserName,
        LoginModel.Password, LoginModel.RememberMe, false);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(LoginModel.UserName);
        var claims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
        ClaimsIdentity id = new (claims, "ApplicationCookie",
            ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            new ClaimsPrincipal(id));
        return Redirect("/");
    }

    return Page();
}
```

In Startup class I registered my policy like that

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("IsAdmin", policy => { policy.RequireClaim("Admin"); });             
});
```

But I can't access to this PageModel when I am in admin account

```
[Authorize(Policy = "IsAdmin")]
public class UserPanel : PageModel
{}
```

Please, tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Is your `Admin` claim part of the claims that you retrieve for the user? Check the output from `GetClaimsAsync`.

Comment: @poke Admin claim is exists there

Comment: What value does this `Admin` claim have?

Comment: @poke claim has got ```IsAdmin``` type and ```Admin``` value

Comment: Okay, then it is not a `Admin` claim but an `IsAdmin` claim. You will need to do `RequireClaim("IsAdmin")` because `RequireClaim` checks against the claim **type**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
options.AddPolicy("IsAdmin", policy => { policy.RequireClaim("Admin"); });
```

[`AuthorizationPolicyBuilder.RequireClaim(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationpolicybuilder.requireclaim?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authorization_AuthorizationPolicyBuilder_RequireClaim_System_String_) checks for the existance of a claim with the specified claim *type*. It will not look at claim values but just check whether there exists *any* claim that has a matching claim type.

Since your claim is of claim type `IsAdmin` with the claim value `Admin`, you would have to check for the `IsAdmin` claim instead:

```
// check for the claim type `IsAdmin`
options.AddPolicy("IsAdmin", policy => policy.RequireClaim("IsAdmin"));
```

You can also use [the other overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationpolicybuilder.requireclaim?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authorization_AuthorizationPolicyBuilder_RequireClaim_System_String_System_String___) that also checks for claim values in addition to the claim type:

```
// check for the claim type `IsAdmin` with value `Admin`
options.AddPolicy("IsAdmin", policy => policy.RequireClaim("IsAdmin", "Admin"));
```